# InvalidArgumentError: Specified a list with shape [60,9] from a tensor with shape [56,9]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

After running my model for one epoch it crashed with following error message:

*InvalidArgumentError:    Specified a list with shape [60,9] from a tensor with shape [56,9]
[[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
[[sequential_7/lstm_17/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_29986]*

This happened after I changed the LSTM Layer to `stateful=True` and had to pass
the `batch_input_shape` Argument instead of the `input_shape`

Below is my code, I'm sure it has something to do with the shape of my data:

```
test_split = 0.2
history_points = 60
n = int(histories.shape[0] * test_split)

histories_train = histories[:n]
y_train = next_values_normalized[:n]

histories_test = histories[n:]
y_test = next_values_normalized[n:]

next_values_test = next_values[n:]

print(histories_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

-->(1421, 60, 9)
-->(1421, 1)

# model architecture

´´´model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128, stateful=True,return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(60,history_points, 9)))
model.add(LSTM(units=64,stateful=True,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=32))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20))
ADAM=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=ADAM)

model.fit(x=histories_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=50, shuffle=False, validation_split=0.2,verbose=1)
´´´
```

Comment: I have the same problem at the moment. The reason could be: You fit on 80% of your training data (20% is Val), so your training data has 1136 samples. Using batch size 60, you have 18 Batches of 60 samples and one batch of 56 samples. It seems that it expects the training data to be divisable in full batches. Did you already solve your problem?

Answer (score 11):

For a stateful LSTM, the batch size should be chosen in a way, so that the number of samples is divisible by the batch size. See also here:

[Keras: What if the size of data is not divisible by batch_size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974340/keras-what-if-the-size-of-data-is-not-divisible-by-batch-size)

In your case, considering that you take 20% from your training data as a validation set, you have 1136 samples remaining. So you should choose a batch size by which 1136 is divisible.

Additionally, you could for example remove some samples or reuse samples to be able to choose various batch sizes.