# Tensorflow Training Crashes in last step of first epoch for audio classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I was trying to convert a custom DNN network originally written in Pytorch to Tensorflow 2 that  has input shape required as (batchsize,39,101,1). After using the  feature extractor and  getting dimensions of the train and validation datasets with the compatible dimensions- (total_samples,39,101,1), I tried to train the model using model.fit. In the very last step of the first epoch, I am facing an error as listed below, that suggests my tensor shape is changing somehow. I don't know why this happening in the last step only. My callbacks are quite simple ones related to model checkpoint and earlystopping as displayed below.My DB is from Google Speech dataset v0.01. I believe this is happening before the validation step starts. Would be great if anyone could help with any suggestions to get it fixed.

Here are my train and validation datasets dimensions:

```
print(x_tr.shape) -> (17049, 39, 101, 1)
print(y_tr.shape) -> (17049, 10)
print(x_val.shape) -> (4263, 39, 101, 1)
print(y_val.shape) -> (4263, 10)
modelname, input_shape, numclass = 'CRNN', (39,101,1), 10

model = modelcreator.getmodel(modelname, input_shape, numclass)
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, min_delta=0.0001) 
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

> Epoch 1/100 266/267 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss:
> 0.9436 - accuracy: 0.6963
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 history=model.fit(x_tr, y_tr ,epochs=100, callbacks=[es,mc], batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
> 107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> --> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 109
> 110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,
> use_multiprocessing)    1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
> 1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)    1099               if data_handler.should_sync:    1100
> context.async_wait()
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 778       else:
> 779         compiler = "nonXla"
> --> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 781
> 782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 805       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
> 806       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
> --> 807       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
> 808     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
> 809       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)    2827     with self._lock:
> 2828       graph_function, args, kwargs =
> self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
> -> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access    2830     2831   @property
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)    1846
> resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],    1847
> captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
> -> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)    1849     1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs,
> cancellation_manager=None):
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
> 1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
> 1923       return
> self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
> -> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))    1925
> forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
> 1926         args,
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
> 548               inputs=args,
> 549               attrs=attrs,
> --> 550               ctx=ctx)
> 551         else:
> 552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(
>
> ~/Desktop/Spoken_Keyword_Spotting/newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
> 58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
> 61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
> 62     if name is not None:
>
> InvalidArgumentError:    Specified a list with shape [64,512] from a
> tensor with shape [25,512]     [[{{node
> TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
> [[functional_3/lstm_1/PartitionedCall]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_13255]
>
> Function call stack: train_function -> train_function ->
> train_function

Comment: If you are getting error last batch of the epoch, what would happen if you set batch-size as "1", would you get the same error?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, I was able to find the answer. Yes with bs 1 it worked

Answer (score 0):

I figured it from the link below. Based on the answer here:
[InvalidArgumentError: Specified a list with shape [60,9] from a tensor with shape [56,9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309194/invalidargumenterror-specified-a-list-with-shape-60-9-from-a-tensor-with-shap)

My model consisted of a LSTM layer at the end with return sequences=True. So in the last epoch as the batch that received had fewer samples than batch size. Faced this issue